# How to remove space between css flex contains

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a table structure using css flex box

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OqbPLo

I have a container with the elements spaced using flex `justify-content: space-between;` but is it possible to remove the space
in between the divs so they sit next to each other.

I can get the effecy I want by making the cell width 100% bu then I can't control the width of the cells

```
*{
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.content-wrapper,
.content-header{
  display: contents;
}

.content-header{
  .grid-cell{
      font-weight: bold;
    }
}

.grid-wrapper{
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.grid-cell{
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  white-space: no-wrap;
}
.grid-header,
.grid-content{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  //align-content: stretch;
}

.grid-cell-1{
  flex-basis: 80px;
}
.grid-cell-2{
  flex-basis: 68px;
}
.grid-cell-3{

}
.grid-cell-4{
  flex-basis:58px;
}
.grid-cell-5{
  flex-basis: 58px;
}
.grid-cell-6{
  flex-basis: 58px;
}
.grid-cell-7{
  flex-basis: 58px;
}
.grid-cell-8{
  flex-basis: 58px;
}
.grid-cell-9{
  flex-basis: 58px;
}
.grid-cell-10{
  flex-basis: 58px;
}
.grid-cell-11{
  flex-basis: 58px;
}
.grid-cell-12{
  flex-basis: 58px;
}
.grid-cell-13{
  flex-basis: 58px;
}


@media(max-width: 700px){
  .grid-header{
    display: none;
  }

  .grid-content{
    display: initial;
  }

  .grid-cell{
    display: inline;
  }

  .grid-content{
    display: flex;
  }

  .content-wrapper{
    display: initial;
  }

  .content-header{
    display: block;

  }
}
```

Comment: Why even use `space:between` is you don't want space between?

Comment: So like this? - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/OqbPWr

Comment: Sorry I should have said I want the table to be 100% width

Comment: _“I'm trying to create a table structure using css flex box”_ - and what made you come up with that bad idea …? There is no inherent “connection” between those fake table cells, so you won’t get any “table features” like equal-width cells within columns, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand your question. But I think if you add a max-width to your .grid-cell class you might get what you want.

```
.grid-cell{
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

See the [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/burlyn84/Ldz6fhj9/1/)

However, if you want this to be responsive, this solution will not totally solve the issue.

A more responsive way to accomplish this is to switch to using

```
display: grid;
```

See the grid option [here](https://jsfiddle.net/burlyn84/Ldz6fhj9/12/)

Edited to add note - if you want spacing on the grid display, add a margin to the grid-cells.